# Simple HTTP server that will send the same file for all requests?

Tags: command-line-interface, http, debugging

I need to debug a XML-RPC application, which sends XML replies over HTTP. I have a sample XML reply (i.e. data from the server, sent to the client that isn't working), I'd like to debug my application. Ideally I'd like a simple HTTP server that will serve one file in reply to all requests. Someone requests `/`? Send them this file. Someone makes a post to `/server/page.php` with a certain cookie? Just send them this file. I don't care about multithreading, or security. I will only need to use this for a few hours to debug. I have root on the machine.

i.e. I'm hoping there's something as easy to use as this:

```
simple_http_server -p 12445 -f my_test_file
```

I'm aware of python's `SimpleHTTPServer` module, but I'm not sure how to make it work in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `inetd` installed, <strike>just create a script like</strike> (I made a mistake, the script is not needed)

<strike>#!/bin/bash

    cat $1</strike>

then add the line to inetd.conf

```
http stream  tcp   nowait root  /bin/cat cat /some/other/dir/file.txt
```

With Python just extend the `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler` class and define a `do_GET` method, then run as described in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#module-BaseHTTPServer), e.g.

```
import BaseHTTPServer
class HTTPHandlerOne(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self): self.wfile.write("test\r\n")

def run(server_class=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer,
        handler_class=BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()

run(handler_class=HTTPHandlerOne)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a mod_rewrite rule to an apache vhost that would rewrite all requests back to the file you want to serve.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName onefilevhost.local

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)? http://onefilevhost.local/serve/this/file.txt
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) quite easy. Install sinatra doing `gem install sinatra` and create a `test_page.rb` file like this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/*' do
  File.read('/server/page.php')
end
```

If you don't have `$RUBYOPT=rubygems` on your shell, add `require 'rubygems'` at the beginning.

You can run it with `ruby test_page.rb`. It will listen on port 4567 by default.